# json formatting of query results

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with getting the right format of json data.

I have some query where I want to retrieve the Documents per hour, and return it as json. (the query gives the right results)

```
docs = Document.objects.filter(uploadid= num)
                       .extra({'hour' : "hour(timestamp)"})
                       .values('hour')
                       .annotate(count_ph=Count('id'))
response_data = list(docs)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

this gives a result like

`[{"count_ph": 6, "hour": 12}, {"count_ph": 2, "hour": 13}, {"count_ph": 2, "hour": 14}]`

But what I want to return is just the data 
`[[6,12], [2,13], [2,14]]`  .

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: you may be interested in **[values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list)** where it produces tuple with values only in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated:**

You should be able to achieve this using [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list), and specify what fields to be returned, like so:

```
docs = Document.objects.filter(uploadid= num)
                       .extra({'hour' : "hour(timestamp)"})
                       .annotate(count_ph=Count('id'), distinct=True)
                       .values_list('hour', 'count_ph')
response_data = list(docs)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

**As a side note**: you may need to take care of JSON non-serializable fields like **datetime**.

Comment: this gives me list of all the results in the database (with a certain 'uploadid'), as if it ignores the Count function that I wanted.

Comment: @Laura, please see my updates, you need to specify what fields to be returned in your **values_list** just like you did in your **values**, also to avoid duplicate, add `Count` with **distinct=True**, with `values_list('hour', 'count_ph')` should do.